# Firestore onUpdate array before/after compare returns the whole new array instead of the difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of objects (`bill_list`) within a Firestore document.  When an object is added to the array, I want to trigger an event targeting *just* the new object. (node v10.15.3)

I'm using a negated Array.filter() to capture the newly added object.

**local test function**

```
let arrA = [objA, objB];
let arrB = [objA];
let difference = arrA.filter(x => !arrB.includes(x));
console.log(difference);
```

**index.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.billAdded = functions.firestore
      .document('{region}/bill_data')
      .onUpdate((content, context) => {
            //changed LETs to grab only the array for clarity
            let arrB = content.before.data().bill_list;
            let arrA = content.after.data().bill_list;
            let difference = arrA.filter(x => !arrB.includes(x));

            stateChange(arrB);
            stateChange(arrA);
            stateChange(difference);


            return 0;
        });

function stateChange(newState) {
            //logging done in timeout function to help the logs line up sequentially
    return setTimeout( () => {
            console.log(newState);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Array.filter() performs as expected when run locally; the console output is simply `[objB]`.

When I deploy, however, console output is always the full content of arrA.bill_list; i.e., the above outputs `[objA, objB]`...if I add then add objC to bill_list, the output is then `[objA, objB, objC]`, and so on.

When adding an array element:

```
arrB[]
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' } ]

arrA[]
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' },
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr0000', name: 'test bill', uc_billNum: 's0000' } ]

difference[]
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' },
12:44:09.056 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr0000', name: 'test bill', uc_billNum: 's0000' } ]
```

When removing an array element:

```
arrB[]
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' },
12:39:50.297 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr0000', name: 'test bill', uc_billNum: 's0000' } ]

arrA[]
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' } ]

difference[]
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded [ { lc_billNum: 'hr3219',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded name: 'US Call Center Worker and Consumer Protection Act',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's1792' },
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded { lc_billNum: 'hr1711',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded name: 'No Tax Breaks for Outsourcing Act',
12:39:50.396 PM billAdded uc_billNum: 's780' } ]
```

What am I missing wrt Firestore and Array properties, or does Firebase Cloud Functions have a problem with Array.filter()?

Comment: what does your arrB and arrB returns inse `onUpdate` method? It's possible that you have auto generated keys within those objects, therefore they'll always differ from each other.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  Will try separately logging the contents of arrA & arrB, then update the question tonight.

Comment: alright, added Firebase Functions log output for `arrA`, `arrB`, and `difference` arrays.  I *am* using autogen doc ids, but i'm not comparing *the docs* (AFAICT, at least), just the array properties; It looks like the `Array.includes()` method simply isn't triggering, so `Array.filter()` isn't filtering anything out...Does the Node.js env employed by Functions just *not know* what `Array.includes()` is??

Comment: I'm finding the same issue.  Even when trying `.has()` or `indexOf()` methods.